# matching values (multiple if-functions) between two files and pasting the values

Tags: perl

I have two txt files with multiple columns. This is how the first file (`$frequency`) looks like:

```
C1    C2    A  a   B   b   C   c   D   d
text   1    0  1   0   0   0   0   0   0
text   2    1  0   5   4   0   0   0   0
text   3    0  0   0   0   10  11  3   6
text   4    1  0   9   4   0   2   0   0
text   5    5  3   0   0   6   7   4   0
```

So C2 contains all positions from 1 to 20000. Columns A-d contain numberical values all equal or bigger than 0.

This is how the second file (`$variants`) looks like

```
C1    C2    C3   C4  
text   2    A    D  
text   4    B    C 
text   5    A    B,D
```

C2 here contains some values between 1 and 20000. C3 and C4 contain letters between A-D (like the column names in table 1 but all capital letters). What I now want to do is the following: match the value in C2 from `$variants` with the value in C2 from `$frequency` and then check which letter is in C3 of `$variants` and then copy the corresponding values (so correct line and correct columns with capital and small letter) from `$frequency`to two new columns in `$variants`. The same then needs to be done for C4 of `$variants`.

EDIT: It is also possible sometimes that C4 in `$variants`contains two letters seperated by a ','. For both of these letters the values from `$frequency` should appear in the output

This is how the output should look like, based on this example

```
C1    C2    C3    C4    C5   C6   C7   C8  C9  C10
text  2     A     D     1    0    0    0   empty  
text  4     B     C     9    4    0    2   empty
text  5     A     B,D   5    3    0    0    4   0
```

I've started with the script, but I'm stuck at some point where I need to compare the values as well as the letters.

This is what I have so far:

```
my $table1 = prompt("Give the name of the file with variants:\n");
open(my $variants, '<',$table1) || die "Could not open file $table1 $!";

my $table2 = prompt("Give the name of the file with the frequencies: \n");
open(my $frequency, '<',$table2) || die "Could not open file $table2 $!";

my (@position, @A, @a, @B, @b, @C, @c, @D, @d); #instead of using hashes I was trying to put all the values in arrays, because I don't know how to hash multiple columns from a file.

while(<$frequency>){
    my @column = split(/\t/); # split on tabs
    $position[$_] .= "$column[1] "; # I want to assign the correct column values to the arrays
    $Afor[$_] .= "$column[2] ";
    $arev[$_] .= "$column[3] ";
    $Bfor[$_] .= "$column[4] ";
    $brev[$_] .= "$column[5] ";
    $Cfor[$_] .= "$column[6] ";
    $crev[$_] .= "$column[7] ";
    $Dfor[$_] .= "$column[8] ";
    $drev[$_] .= "$column[9] ";
}

while(<$variants>){
    next if /^\s*#/; # skipping some lines
    next if /^\s*"/;
    chomp;
my ($chr, $pos, $refall, $altall) = split;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this, because I cannot figure out now how I can check for the correct line and the corresponding column in `$frequencies`. Could someone help me with that?

Comment: You tried to explain how the output should be created, but it would be much easier when you could post a *complete* example with input files and expected output so that we can test our solutions.

Comment: @amon I changed the input and output example to better reflect the reality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important first step is usually choosing the right data structure to hold your data.  I think the easiest structure for the contents of the frequency file, for this purpose, is an array of hashes.  Like this:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use English '-no_match_vars';

my ($variants_file, $frequency_file) = @ARGV; # take filename from command line

open my $variants,  '<', $variants_file   or die "Could not open file $variants_file: $!";
open my $frequency, '<', $frequency_file  or die "Could not open file $frequency_file $!";

# parse the header fields
my (undef, undef, @header) = do {
  my $header_line = <$frequency>;
  chomp $header_line;
  split /\t/, $header_line;
};

my @frequency_data;
my $expect_pos = 1; # starting position
while (<$frequency>){
    chomp;
    my(undef, $pos, @column) = split /\t/; # split on tabs
    unless ($pos == $expect_pos) {
      die "On line $INPUT_LINE_NUMBER: expected data for position $expect_pos, instead found position $pos";
    }
    @{ $frequency_data[$pos] }{@header} = @column;
    ++$expect_pos;
}
```

Then it's easy to access the frequency data by position and letter:

```
<$variants>;  # throw away header
while(<$variants>){
    next if /^\s*[#\"]/; # skipping some lines
    chomp;
    my ($text, $pos, $refall, $altall) = split;
    my @ref_data = @{ $frequency_data[$pos] }{$refall, lc($refall)};
    my @alt_data = @{ $frequency_data[$pos] }{$altall, lc($altall)};
    print join("\t", $text, $pos, @ref_data, @alt_data), "\n";
}
```

With the recent edits to your question (multiple columns in the `$variants`), the above snippet could be generalized to:

```
<$variants>;
while (<$variants>) {
  next if ...
  chomp;
  my ($text, $pos, @cols) = split /\t/;
  my @data = map {@{ $frequency_data[$pos] }{$_, lc $_}}  # column to values
             map { split /,/ } @cols;                     # split cols at comma
  print join("\n", $text, $pos, @cols, @data), "\n";
}
```

I hope that's helpful.

Comment: A lot of syntax errors and asking for explicit package names near all `@`

Comment: @kdkeck What's the meaning of `Use English 'no-match vars'`?

Comment: @kdkeck And why are you now using `$expect_pos` and `$pos` instead of `$position`?

Comment: @amon What's the meaning of Use English 'no-match vars'? And why are you now using $expect_pos and $pos instead of $position?

Comment: @user1987607 The `English` module provides long names for so-called punctuation variables. `$.` is the line number, but English provides `$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER` for that variable. The `-no_match_vars` option when importing English avoids a runtime penalty for all regex matches (neccessary due to an unfortunate design acciddent). I changed the name to `$expect_pos` because it conveys the meaning of that variable better: It's the position we are expecting there.

Comment: @amon Thanks. This solution seems to work fine. I've however noticed that in my inputfile there can be two letters seperated by a comma in C4. See the edit in my first post. Where and how can I add in the script that the values for both letters should be in the output. Should I do an extra `split` ?

Comment: @user1987607 Yes, it is an extra split – I did it inside a `map` expression.

Comment: @amon For making it easier, I didn't mention in the input example that `$variants` contains still a lot more columns then the 4 mentioned. I'm using these other columns to do other things in the `while $variants` loop, so therefore I would like not to use this `@cols`, I would only like to split the C4 column on ','